# Problem with Displaying Custom Theme Page's Content

Tags: theme-development, loop, pages, page-template

1. I've created a custom theme, and I want to display a custom theme page that I created, whose file name is 
   `page-about.php`.
2. The only way that I know that it's possible to display custom theme pages in WordPress is to make their files templates, and then create a page via the `WP-Admin` whose template is of the desired file,
   so what I did, is added at the top of `page-about.php` the comment in PHP:
   `Template Name: About Me`.
3. I, then, created a page via the `WP-Admin` called `page-about`.
4. The contents of the pages are printed via the following loop in my `functions.php` page:

   ```
   function display_all_pages() {
   $pages = get_pages();
   foreach ($pages as $page) {
           $id = $page->post_title;
           $id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $id));
           $class = "page";
           $content = $page->post_content;
           echo ('<div ' . 'id="' . $id . '"' . 'class="' . $class . '">' . $content . '</div>');
       }
   }
   ```
5. And this is the content of the `page-about.php` file:

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   *  Template Name: About Me
   */
   get_header();
   ?>

   <?php echo "hello"; ?>

   <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

   <p>
   This is the About Me page.
   </p>

   </body>
   ```
6. I've checked by doing `var_dump` on `$page` inside the loop, and saw that `post-content` of `about-page` is empty. The problem is that my loop doesn't print anything. It makes sense to me that the `post-content` is empty, because the I inserted no content to `page-about` on `WP-Admin`. But, on the other hand, I saw in an old video, from about [here](https://youtu.be/9HCxKyj1SV0?t=329) that I did something that should work.

Why doesn't what I do work, and what do I need to do to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to run your `display_all_pages` function in your template?  Because, from your code, it doesn't appear that you are.

Comment: Yes, `display_all_pages` runs, and displays successfully all the other pages that are were created.

Just a side note: I don't have a `page.php` file. Is this relevant?

My website is a one-pager, so `display_all_pages` is called only in my `index.php` file.

Comment: No, it's not relevant, but it is a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is stemming from what you said about not having any content in the about page.  That content that you are trying to request would come from the content wysiwyg in the back of wordpress.  Anything you print out on the template doesn't automatically get stored in the database, which is what you're requesting using that function.

Comment: Then how can I print the contents of the the file?
I assume that there's a standard way to do that.

Basically, I just want to create the file such that I could use PHP in it, and edit conveniently via my text editor.

Comment: Then you're going to want to use the get_template_part function.  But i'd recommend removing get_header from your file, so you don't load it twice.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Is it possible for me to build the page not as a template?